# What is "time-dependent evolution of the complex noncovalent interaction networks" and why this is important?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, molecular-dynamics

From [Maximilian Scheurer, Peter Rodenkirch, Marc Siggel, Rafael C. Bernardi, Klaus Schulten, Emad Tajkhorshid and Till Rudack Biophysical Journal, Volume 114, Issue 3, 577-583](http://www.cell.com/biophysj/pdf/S0006-3495(17)35051-8.pdf):

> One of the most relevant molecular properties that can be investigated
>   by all-atom MD simulations is the time-dependent evolution of the complex noncovalent interaction networks governing
>   such fundamental aspects as molecular recognition, binding strength, and mechanical and structural stability.

What are noncovalent interaction networks? And why their time evolution is important in structural biology. I tried also to use the authors' library [pycontact](https://github.com/maxscheurer/pycontact), but it's not clear to me how to use it.

Comment: @Mithoron, *sigh* fancy name for nothing new. I don't get what is so special about this approach. Applying a threshold to a pidst 2D matrix, ins't it trivial thing to do?

Comment: @Mithoron why the downvotes? Is the question not legitimate?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt, as opposed to grilled cheese an "interaction" based on contact map is a bit arbitrary selection. For example 2 amino acids are 0.2nm apart do they interact what if they are 0.21nm what if the threshold is 0.3nm and they are 0.30002nm apart have they stopped to contact?

Comment: This is not homework; please don't flag it as such.